# Change /tmp (to increase available space) on live system?

Tags: hard-disk, disk-image, tmp

I use Ubuntu 20.04, on a machine that has a limited system drive.

I came across a build script that checks for available size in `/tmp`, and it refuses to run if it doesn't see 12 GB available, which I do not have on system drive.

However, I do have another NTFS drive on this machine; since its NTFS, I cannot really use it directly, but I can create a disk image.

So, I thought of creating a 16 GB ext3 image on the NTFS partition, then mount this as /tmp.

So, I tried:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=tmp16.img bs=16M count=0 seek=1024
mkfs.ext3 ./tmp16.img
fdisk -l ./tmp16.img
e2label ./tmp16.img tmp16
```

So far, so good - all of that worked; but then I try to mount:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount /path/to/ntfs/tmp16.img /tmp
mount: /tmp: mount point not mounted or bad option.
```

Ups, must be an old memory of mine from somewhere, that `/tmp` is a separate mount - it turns out, on this machine, `/tmp` is not a separate mount:

```
$ mount | grep tmp
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=3970256k,nr_inodes=992564,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=802768k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/snapd/ns type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=802768k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=802764k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
tmpfs on /run/netns type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=802768k,mode=755)
```

Well ... is there any way that I can use this disk image as `/tmp` on this machine - and is there a way to do that, without having to reboot the machine (which would be needed, I think, if something has to be done int `/etc/fstab`?)

If not, is there any other way I could make use of the available NTFS space and use it as `/tmp` - preferably, without having to reboot the machine?

Comment: why not edit the script so that it uses /var/tmp/ or some other directory with enough space available (whether it's a mount-point or not)?   It's not a great idea to mount another fs over /tmp unless you do it very early in the boot process (before anything really starts using it) - files that were already in /tmp won't be available when a new fs is mounted on top of it (even overlayfs doesn't really solve that problem if you need RW access to the older files in /tmp)

Comment: Existing open files will be available/usable and nothing will break. The issue might arise with directories but those could simply be copied/recreated.

Comment: @cas You really should not need to edit a well-written script but just set `TMPDIR` prior to running it. Unfortunately I don’t see a lot of scripts that are this well written.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov when you mount a filesystem, you can no longer see, or open, the files & dirs that were in the mount-point before the mount.  Any already open file handles are still valid until they're closed.  Try making directory /tmp/junk, copy a bunch of files & dirs into it. run ls on it.  then `truncate -s 1G /tmp/1gb.img; mkfs.ext4 /tmp/1gb.img; sudo mount -o loop /tmp/1gb.img /tmp/junk`.   run `ls /tmp/junk` again, all you'll see is the `lost+found` dir.

Comment: *Any already open file handles are still valid until they're closed.* - exactly what I was talking about. Mounting something on top of `/tmp` is relatively safe.

Comment: Already opened files are not the only things in /tmp to be concerned about. Other important things include: all the /tmp/systemd-private-*/ directories that systemd creates for running services; private tmp dirs for uids under /tmp/user;  socket files for for ssh-agent, tmux, dbus, and more. All of these become inaccessible when a filesystem is mounted over an existing, in-use /tmp dir.  As I said, not a great idea to mess with it, especially when there are many better alternatives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```bash
sudo mount -o loop /path/to/ntfs/tmp16.img /tmp
```

should work. No idea why you're using `remount`.

TBO `sudo mount -o bind  /path/to/ntfs/empty_dir /tmp` could work as well. NTFS has all the features required to store Linux files https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfs-3g : *"it can handle special files like symbolic links, devices, and FIFOs; moreover it provides standard management of file ownership and permissions, including POSIX ACLs"*. NTFS-3g might be quite slower when working with thousands of small files but otherwise it's OK.

Comment: Many thanks, @ArtemS.Tashkinov - that does, indeed, work! I thought I had to have remount because I though `/tmp` was mounted (which it wasn't); given it was a directory, though, it can be used as a mount point - I was a bit afraid that might cause a conflict, but no; simply the content of the mounted image shadows what else existed in `/tmp` previously.

Comment: `-o remount,new_option1,new_option2` is used to change the mount point options. You simply want to mount something on top of the existing mount.